# c++ gdb breakpoint not hit

Tags: c++, boost, gdb, breakpoints

I change post totally.
because I work in south korea army.
but south korea army internet computer is forbid upload file.
so I really upload my source code. but I can't .
so I try debug very very simple program with gdb.
but It is still not working.

my system is

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

in cloud IDE called "nitrous"

and g++ , gdb version is

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8
```

I write very simple code : simple.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

compile with "-g" and gdb execute

```
nitrous@ubuntu-108903:~/code$ g++ -g simple.cpp -o simple
nitrous@ubuntu-108903:~/code$ gdb simple
```

and set break main and run

```
Reading symbols from simple...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400861: file simple.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/nitrous/code/simple
Hello World!
During startup program exited normally.
```

Even very simple helloworld program not work breakpoint.
just print out During startup program exited norally.

Comment: You forgot to show a minimal example (SSCCE)

Comment: The question is quite unclear. Maybe this helps, though:

The _usual_ way to set a breakpoint at that line would be

    `b main.cpp:21`

Comment: @sehe add some example. sorry for poor example.. this posting is my first ask.

Comment: That's not the correct source, because it's line 7, not 21. Also, you cannot set a breakpoint on a comment line (it will set it at the next line with executable statements I think). Try disabling optimizations (-O0) and make sure you compile **and** link with `-g` (make sure you do a full rebuild)

Comment: @sehe I explicitly comment "line no.21", because that source code is comment removed version(for Readability. actually, raw source code has many comment. so I remove some comment). and I try also "-g" and "-O0" and link with "-g"

Comment: It's not about the code. We need code, effective compile and link commands. Perhaps versions. But in this case, it's more: **[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**.

Comment: By the way, kudos for actually learning how to debug. I'm sorry you'll have to learn the hard lesson of software development so early: you're having to "debug" (troubleshoot) your inability to debug. Still the exact same skill though. Reduce & eliminate until you find the cause.

Comment: Have you tried just `break main` by the way. Using `start` is an alias for `break main` followed by `run`

Comment: @sehe thank you for help. but I really upload my project or compliable source code. but I can't.(security reason.) so I try debug very simple program .please see posting.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.3 comes with gdb 7.7.1. Your gdb 7.8 might not be totally compatible; do you know where it's from? (a PPA? Compiled from source?) . Try `/usr/bin/gdb` and it may work better.

Comment: my gdb is 7.11.1 and it works fine with above sample code.

Answer (score 0):

> I set a break point, but it's not hit. What is problem?

The most likely problem is that your program terminates *before* reaching `main`. (A typical dynamically linked program will execute several hundred 1000s of instructions before reaching `main`.)

Run your program under GDB until GDB stops with `SIGSEGV`. Execute GDB `where` command. Observe that `main` is not on the stack.

Once you've confirmed that `main` is not on the stack, ask a different question (assuming you still don't understand the reason for crash).

Comment: thank you for answer. so sorry please question once more? I totally edit postting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that gdb for some reason failed to set breakpoint. Try to run gdb with sudo.
Btw, could you run strace on generated elf and grep for `ptrace`? It should be something like follow `strace -f -o syscall.txt gdb ./simple.out`.